# What is the equivalent of Android LiveData in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-livedata

Android's LiveData allows to update the UI when the activity is in an active state. So if a background operation has finished while the activity is paused, the activity won't be notified and thus the app won't crush. Can Flutter perform the same behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by crush ?

Comment: Well, If the background operation has finished, then it will try to update the activity, and because the activity is paused ( when the activity not on the screen thus inaccessible) the app will crush

Comment: That's not a problem in flutter

Comment: How is that? Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to listen to the application state.

```
class AppLifecycleReactor extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppLifecycleReactor({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppLifecycleReactorState createState() => new _AppLifecycleReactorState();
}

class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  AppLifecycleState _notification;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() { _notification = state; });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('Last notification: $_notification');
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense thanks. This is why building apps with flutter is far more easier than Android.

Answer (score 15):

For people interested in an equivalent of LiveData for other scenarios, I present you StreamController:

```
class ExampleViewModel {

  StreamController<bool> loggedInStream = StreamController<bool>();

  logIn() { loggedInStream.add(true); }
}


class ExampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ExampleScreenState();
}

class ExampleScreenState extends State<ExampleScreen> {

  ExampleViewModel _viewModel;
  BuildContext _ctx;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _viewModel = ExampleViewModel()
    _viewModel.loggedInStream.stream.listen( (loggedIn) {
      if ( loggedIn != null && loggedIn ) {
        Navigator.of(_ctx).pushReplacementNamed("/home");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _ctx = context;

    var loginBtn =
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: _viewModel.logIn(true),
        child: Text(
          "LOGIN",
          style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
        )
      ),
      color: Colors.green,
      textColor: Colors.white,
    );

    return loginBtn;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _viewModel.loggedInStream.close();
  }

}
```

You can subscribe to it just like a LiveData, using:

```
loggedInStream.stream.listen( (data) { code } )
```

And you should clear the listeners in dispose to avoid memory leaks:

```
loggedInStream.close()
```

This code basically do the following things:

1. Creates a screen with a button.
2. Listen to a Stream (observe a LiveData).
3. When you click the button, it changes the value.
4. The listener (observer) is triggered.
5. Launches new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: [Flutterx Live Data](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterx_live_data)

There is no need to observe App lifecycle: widget are built only when the app is resumend
This library integrates perfectly LiveData concepts, also is well documented.
Is developed on Flutter 1.14.x-dev you need master flutter channel at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late for the party,
My colleague and I have developed a library that mimics the live data of android, on flutter.
Check it out:
https://pub.dev/packages/stream_live_data